# Обзор функции sockMerchant. Как улучшить её временную сложность?

Tags: алгоритм, c++14

```
int sockMerchant(int& n, vector<int>& ar) {
    set<int> s;
    for(int i{}; i < n; ++i){
        s.insert(ar[i]);
    }

    int pairs{};

    for(auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it){
        int k{};
        for(int i{}; i < n; ++i){
            if(ar[i] == *it){
               k++;
            }
        }

        pairs += (k / 2);
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Заполнение сета `O(n*lb(n))`
- Проход по сету `O(n)`

  - Проход по массиву `O(n)`

Получается `O(n**2)`

---

Улучшить - вместо сета увеличивать кличество в map - будет `O(n*lb(n))`

```
map <int, int> s;

for (int i{}; i < n; ++i)
  ++s[ar[i]];

int pairs{};

for (auto p : s)
  pairs += p.second / 2;
```

PS: Что-то алгоритм подозрительный.

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ. Реализовал как смог для решения этой задачи https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sock-merchant/problem

Comment: Хм.. Тогда вроде алгоритм правильный, но при ограничении до 100 твой тоже должен был нормально работать.

Comment: нужно исправить p->second на p.second. Мне пишет Правка должна быть не менее 6 символов

Comment: Да, точно. Стрелка была бы через итератор, а тут пара.